# SDL_TTF header giving me trouble

Tags: c++, sdl, header-files, sdl-ttf

I've been trying to get SDL set up on my computer after a virus forced me to reset to factory condition. Getting SDL running with my IDE, CodeBlocks, was easy, but getting the extension libraries set up has been less so. CodeBlocks recognizes the existence of the libraries, but is giving me multiple errors within the SDL_ttf header and the SDL_image header. 
The section of the code that is giving me trouble is this:

```
/* Set up for C function definitions, even when using C++ */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

The first line generates the error "error: expected unqualified-id before string constant", and the third line generates the above error and the error "error: expected '}' before end of line". 
My guess was that this might have something to with SDL being written in C, and maybe my CodeBlocks hasn't been configured to recognize C.

Edit: The test source code is this:

```
SDL_Surface* imageBlitingFunctions::loadText(Uint8 red, Uint8 blue, Uint8 green, std::string fontname, int fontSize, std::string text)
{

    SDL_Color textColor = {red, blue, green};

    TTF_Font *font1 = TTF_OpenFont(fontname.c_str(), fontSize);

    SDL_Surface *message1 = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font1, text.c_str(), textColor);

    return message1;
}
```

Comment: ifdef'ed extern C is very much standard way to make C functions callable from C++, which is completely ok. What compiler you're using? What are exact error messages, and what is test program's source code?

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure the code you posted is the issue. Maybe it's what's before it. Anyway, you should make sure that this not some error in your environment, you can try to make a new c++ project that contains a simple function that is declare as `extern "C"` to look if it already chokes on that.

Comment: It's still giving me "error: expected unqualified-id before string constant".

Comment: I suppose there are no mindreaders here, sorry. The error message you described happens when `extern "C"` block occurs when compiling C code (not C++). Why on earth your C code have defined `__cplusplus` - is beyond my imagination (it obviously can't be done by C compiler itself because it knows it is reserved for C++ only). Check your defines and compiler flags.

Comment: Well I set it up on a different computer, and got a different SDL project running with TTF, so its got to be a problem specifically within my program. I tried debugging, and it handed me the error: "the procedural entry point SDL_getenv could not be located in the dynamic link library SDL.dll."

Comment: What you say doesn't making any sense. If you got compilation error, then under no circumstances it could be run in debugger because no executable was produced during compilation. Please rewrite your question based on your *current* problem and write down things you've tried to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. Apparently the project file had somehow gotten corrupted, so I just transferred the scripts over to another project and everything is working fine.